# Count number of weekdays from the dates passed in where clause in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

How to count the number of weekdays for a given date range passed in where clause. For example in the below example there are 13 records however only 9 of them fall under weekday.

`select * from table_name where startdate > '2019-01-01' and enddate < '2019-01-31'
Date             Day          Asset Price
01-01-2019      Tuesday      A        5
01-01-2019      Tuesday      A        23
02-01-2019      Wednesday    B        20
03-01-2019      Thursday     C        87
04-01-2019      Friday       D        34
04-01-2019      Friday       D        8
05-01-2019      Saturday     E        12
05-01-2019      Saturday     E        56
06-01-2019      Sunday       F       214
07-01-2019      Monday       G        32
08-01-2019      Tuesday      H        45
09-01-2019      Wednesday    I        67`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count days between two dates excluding weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731712/count-days-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends).  From the sound of it, the table you're operating over is noise.  There's also [pure math ways to perform this calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252519/812837), but quite often you want something besides just "weekdays", so wouldn't otherwise be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the correct result, if you run it as is?

```
with table_name (date) as 
(
  values
  '01-01-2019'
, '01-01-2019'
, '02-01-2019'
, '03-01-2019'
, '04-01-2019'
, '05-01-2019'
, '06-01-2019'
, '07-01-2019'
, '08-01-2019'
, '09-01-2019'
)
select 
—- distinct date
count(distinct date)
from table_name
where dayofweek_iso(date(to_date(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'))) < 6
```

Comment: No there are multiple rows for each date. I have edited my sample data.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer accordingly. Is this correct now?

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from table_name
where startdate > '2019-01-01' and enddate < '2019-01-31'
and Day not in ("Saturday", "Sunday")
```

Comment: No this doesn't work as this would give the number of records. I need to know only the number of weekdays.